# error failure writing sector to hd0 and computer boots to initramfs. Cannot acces disk

Tags: boot

Something I do not understand happened and now I cannot boot into ubuntu. This is what's happened. I was using de Déja Dup Backup Tool to copy some files from my home directory to an external disk and I got an error. I don't remember the error message exactly as I didn't think it was important but it went along the lines of "can't read duplicity something".

After the error, I looked into the external hard drive and found .tar files that weren't originally there, whose names started by "duplicity" and some numbers. I deleted them. I tried again to copy my files from the hdd to the external drive and I got the same error as before. After that I unmounted the external disk and I switched off the computer.

I tried to boot and after the grub page, if I pick ubuntu the message "error failure writing sector some numbers to hd0" appears. After that the screen goes blank and after a while console appears that says initramfs. From there I cannot acces my hard drive. And I do not know how to proceed.

I have a dual boot of Windows 10 and Ubuntu 16.04 so I can also choose Windows in the grub page. When doing that the screen goes black for a long time, and after a while a mouse icon pops out that can be moved but the screen remains black. Any idea of what is going on?

Comment: We need the specific error messages to provide exact help, however your messages reads like hardware errors, so I'd check the health of your drive(s), using SMART found on the chips inside the drives. Refer https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Smartmontools   If the drives are healthy, then and only then would I check the logical state of the drive partitions (ie. file system check or `fsck` adjusting for whatever *fs* you are using as you didn't specify)

Comment: @guiverc thanks for the comment. How am I supposed to use SMART if I cannot access the drive though?

Comment: SMART is usually read from a 'live' system (so hdd/ssd is not in use), and it doesn't actually use the media itself, it reads the diagnostics from the chips on the drive, so should the drive be failing, you know that before you've wasted any remaining life left doing diagnostics (ie. leaving that life for getting the most valuable data off).  You use `smartctl`, `gnome-disks` or other alternatives found on 'live' media (eg. Ubuntu install media using the 'try ubuntu' option)